# Using Random() and Greater Than

Tags: arduino-uno

Total Arduino noob, I come from a Python "background", though I barely know that, either.

I'm writing a super simple script that will turn on a bulb when the random number generator generates a number greater than 100. Obviously, I have a syntax problem or something: What am I doing wrong? Secondly, How quickly does `random` query numbers? Is it possible to slow it down? I don't need my bulb turning on 50 times a second.

Thanks! And please be kind; I know this is Googleable, I just lack the prerequisite knowledge to Google this efficiently.

````
/*

*/
int relayPin = 7;
int randomNumber = random(1001);


void setup() {
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);

   
}

void loop() {


if(randomNumber > 100)
  digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);

else{
   digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);}
   
   
}```
````

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: btw, put the ``` on a separate line so that it is invisible

Comment: The problem is that the relay module does not switch. I assume that there is an error in my code.

Comment: yes, logic error ... ask yourself  `when is the value of randomNumber updated?`

Comment: The current code (if you move the random number generation into *loop()*) will switch not just 50 times, but thousands of times per second. Look at some example code to get an idea about how to solve that.

Comment: Start to learn, aka "build knowledge", by looking into some of the provided examples... ;-)

Comment: Start with the blink example and think how you can randomise it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to be discussed in here.

First, the random number generation: in fact, the arduino **does not** generate random numbers. It has a list of numbers on its memory that just "seems" to be random. That's why it's called a pseudo-random number.
So, you need to declare a starting point on this sequence, from which you will get the "random" numbers. This is made with "randomSeed()" in void setup. For example:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); //starts the pseudo-random sequence in a random point,
                             //in this case, the analogRead value of an unconnected pin
}
```

Next, let's generate our number. The variable can be global (as you declared it outside any function), but **you must declare it with "random()" only inside "void loop"**. Otherwise, its value will be assigned just one time (that's what your code is telling it, to do it once).

Here is what I would do:

```
int relayPin = 7;
long randomNumber; //just declares the variable; it must be type "long"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); //starts the pseudo-random sequence in a random point
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  randomNumber = random(0, 301);
  //each time the code loops, it assings another value to randomNumber
  //in this case, the number will be between 0 and 300 (301 is the excluded limit)
    
  if(randomNumber > 100){
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(500); //half a second delay
     
}
```

If you want to have more details about how random numbers are generated in the Arduino, visit the Arduino language Reference:
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/

Comment: Thank you for this! This explanation was very kind and helpful of you! I will implement this after work.